# Import all existing addresses in local bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, local

I started local bitcoind client. And started it as RPC server. I know that i able to get balance only for my account address. But how i can work with all existing addresses? How i can get balances and txs? Maybe exist some db for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import any address you want to watch or "work with" by navigating to console window and sending the following command:

```
bitcoin-cli importaddress "address" "account" <rescan>
```

after blockchain scanning complete you can send

```
bitcoin-cli listtransactions "account" "Count" "skip" watch-only
bitcoin-cli listtransactions "*" 1 0 true
```

So you get all transactions.

You can get all commands from [bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference)

Comment: Thx. Maybe bitcore-node can help me? If i install it and synch it fully would i be able to work with all addresses?

Comment: yeah, also you can do that with bitcoin-core but just with transactions. by enabling -txindex

Comment: Ty so much. @Adam with transactions you mean i would be able to get list of transactions(spent and unspent)?

Comment: to get unspents, you should call listunspents